# Is there a way to await for an if statement to be true?

Tags: function, if-statement, rpc, multiplayer, godot4

I am trying to make a multiplayer godot game, and I want to make sure every @rpc have been read by all peers before continuing to read through the main part of the code.

So I made a variable that increases every time one of the rpc is read.

The problem is that I want to make sure that the main program is stopped while this variable is below the number of players.

I have been searching a lot for documentations, but I only came across *await* which uses signals (so no links to variables), *while* (which just completely freezes the program) and have been trying to find *functions that launches anytime an if statement is true* (without luck).

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. You need to build this.

As you found out `await` works with signals. Well, you can create your own [custom signals](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/signals.html#custom-signals). So in the code where you increment the variable, you can either add a check, or emit a signal, or both.

---

For example, one way would be to define a setter for your variable, and have signal when it changes to the value you want. Then you connect or await it.

```
signal expected_x_reached()

var expected_x:int

var x:int:
    set(mod_value):
        if x == mod_value:
            return

        x = mod_value
        if mod_value == expected_x:
            expected_x_reached.emit()
```

*Addendum: In this scenario, you might want to have a setter for `expected_x` too (since `x == expected_x` can become true because `x` changed or because `expected_x` changed). But I'll keep it as is for clarity.*

---

Be aware that you can define a signal for when a value changes, and connect an annonymous method to check fo the value (which is useful if different parts of your code need to wait for different values):

```
signal x_changed(value:int)

var x:int:
    set(mod_value):
        if x == mod_value:
            return

        x = mod_value
        x_changed.emit(mod_value)
```

In this case the method connected will get the value:

```
obj.x_changed.connect(
    func (value:int) -> void:
        if value == expected_x:
            # do something, emit a signal, whatever
            pass
)
```

---

If is not code you control... You might have to find an adequete existing signal. Or you need to check for it in [`_notification`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-private-method-notification) or some other callback.

Worse case scenario you need to check every frame (because there is no notification mechanism, and you can't add one without a custom build of Godot).

You can check every frame using `_process` or connecting to the `process_frame` signal of the scene tree.

Using `_process` could be like this:

```
func _process(_delta:float) -> void:
    if obj.x == expected_x:
        # do something, emit a signal, whatever
        pass
```

You might do this in your existing nodes, or create a new node to keep track of the variable and emit the signal... Which other nodes can connect to.

---

If you were writing a loop to wait, you should be able to either:

- Convert it to code that runs in `_process` (doing one iteration each frame).
- Use `await`※ on `process_frame`, or on some custom signal.
- Or break it with `call_deferred`. *I'll advice to not abuse this, there is a limit to how many deferred calls you can have going.*

※: I'll also point out that there is a drawback to awaiting: it cannot be cancelled, and a freed object cannot resume from an await (which can result in some nasty bugs). If you run into such problems, consider refactoring from `await` to continuations connecting to the signal using `CONNECT_ONE_SHOT` or having code to disconnect when it is appropiate. The reason being that when objects are freed, they automatically disconnect.